# Upgrading to from rails 5 to 6 and zeitwerk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, circleci, rails-upgrade

We have a rails 5.2.8.1 app and a trying to upgrade to rails 6.1. We have managed to make the application run locally with only minor problems.

However, pushing to our ci (circleCI) we get errors in precompiling the assets.
The error is that the zeitwerk loader (load once) wants to manage `actiontext-6.1.7/app/helpers` which is already managed by the default main loader.

The weird thing is we do not use the load once loader at all..

**loader setup in application.rb**

```
    config.autoload_paths += %W[
      #{config.root}/lib
      #{config.root}/lib/simple_form
      #{config.root}/app/jobs
      #{config.root}/app/jobs/concerns
      #{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns
      #{config.root}/app/mailers/concerns
      #{config.root}/app/models/concerns
      #{config.root}/app/models/reports
      #{config.root}/app/services/pdf_data
      #{config.root}/app/presenters
      #{config.root}/app/assets/templates
      #{config.root}/app/event_handlers
      #{config.root}/app/queries
      #{config.root}/app/concepts
      #{config.root}/vendor/
      #{config.root}/app/pdfs
    ]

    config.eager_load_paths += %W[
      #{config.root}/lib
    ]
```

**error printout:**

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
WEBPACKER_PRECOMPILE=false RAILS_NO_DB=true bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Zeitwerk::Error: loader

#<Zeitwerk::Loader:0x000055eb81710b98
 @autoloaded_dirs=[],
 @autoloads={},
 @collapse_dirs=#<Set: {}>,
 @collapse_glob_patterns=#<Set: {}>,
 @eager_load_exclusions=#<Set: {}>,
 @eager_loaded=false,
 @ignored_glob_patterns=#<Set: {}>,
 @ignored_paths=#<Set: {}>,
 @inflector=ActiveSupport::Dependencies::ZeitwerkIntegration::Inflector,
 @initialized_at=2022-12-07 14:27:29.123263169 +0000,
 @logger=nil,
 @mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x000055eb81710738>,
 @mutex2=#<Thread::Mutex:0x000055eb81710710>,
 @namespace_dirs={},
 @on_load_callbacks={},
 @on_setup_callbacks=[],
 @on_unload_callbacks={},
 @reloading_enabled=false,
 @roots={},
 @setup=false,
 @shadowed_files=#<Set: {}>,
 @tag="rails.once",
 @to_unload={}>


wants to manage directory /home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.1.7/app/helpers, which is already managed by

#<Zeitwerk::Loader:0x000055eb81712f88
 @autoloaded_dirs=[],
 @autoloads={},
 @collapse_dirs=#<Set: {}>,
 @collapse_glob_patterns=#<Set: {}>,
 @eager_load_exclusions=
  #<Set: {"/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/lib/simple_form",
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/models/reports",
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/assets/templates",
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/vendor"}>,
 @eager_loaded=false,
 @ignored_glob_patterns=#<Set: {}>,
 @ignored_paths=#<Set: {}>,
 @inflector=ActiveSupport::Dependencies::ZeitwerkIntegration::Inflector,
 @initialized_at=2022-12-07 14:27:29.122727016 +0000,
 @logger=nil,
 @mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x000055eb81712ab0>,
 @mutex2=#<Thread::Mutex:0x000055eb81712a88>,
 @namespace_dirs={},
 @on_load_callbacks={},
 @on_setup_callbacks=[],
 @on_unload_callbacks={},
 @reloading_enabled=false,
 @roots=
  {"/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/lib"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/lib/simple_form"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/jobs"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/jobs/concerns"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/controllers/concerns"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/mailers/concerns"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/models/concerns"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/models/reports"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/presenters"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/assets/templates"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/event_handlers"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/queries"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/concepts"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/vendor"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/pdfs"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/associations"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/channels"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/controllers"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/decorators"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/forms"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/graphql"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/graphql/concerns"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/helpers"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/interactors"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/mailers"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/models"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/permitters"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/policies"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/public_api"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/serializers"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/services"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/app/validators"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jquery-minicolors-rails-2.2.6.2/app/inputs"=>
    Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/engines/sms/app/concerns"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/engines/sms/app/controllers"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/engines/sms/app/helpers"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/engines/sms/app/inputs"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/engines/sms/app/mailers"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/engines/sms/app/models"=>Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sentry-rails-5.6.0/app/jobs"=>
    Object,
   "/home/circleci/flightlogger-rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/react_on_rails-13.1.0/app/helpers"=>
    Object},
 @setup=false,
 @shadowed_files=#<Set: {}>,
 @tag="rails.main",
 @to_unload={}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `vendor` is added to the autoload paths of the `main` autoloader. It should not be there.

Action Text configures the `once` autoloader ([here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4435b7afe3bf3f2d0f2f3b77aedd44d93219be18/actiontext/lib/action_text/engine.rb#L17-L20)), but with your configuration it cannot do that because `main` manages `vendor` (and therefore all its descendants).

Your configuration should not be adding `vendor`, because `vendor/bundle` is not intended to define a `Bundle` module, right? That directory is not meant to be autoloaded by the application.

Dependencies load themselves.

In addition to removing `vendor` from that configuration, you should also remove these redundant directories that are automatically added by Rails:

```
#{config.root}/app/jobs
#{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns
#{config.root}/app/models/concerns
#{config.root}/app/presenters
#{config.root}/app/event_handlers
#{config.root}/app/queries
#{config.root}/app/concepts
#{config.root}/app/pdfs
```

Comment: Thank you so much! can't believe we did not try this!